# How can we send the table data to mail using php?

Tags: email, sendmail, html-email, phpmailer

[image: Screenshot of my content, which has to be mailed]

i am displaying the daily report submitted by the user now i want to mail the same to email when the send email button is clicked. how can i do that in PHP ?
i used the following code

```
extract($_REQUEST);

if(isset($send_mail)){
    $edata= $_POST['send_msg'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$edata');</script>";
    $ka_semail=$_SESSION['user_email'];
    $subject = "Report";
    $body = $edata;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Info <'.$ka_semail.'>' . "\r\n"; 

$mchk= mail($ka_semail, $subject, $body, $headers);
        if(isset($mchk)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your data Sent sucessfully');</script>";
        header("location:reports.php");
        }
}
?>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <div id="logo_text">
          <a href="index.html">
          <div style="background:#2A0000"><img src="images/kreamsoftlogo.png"/></a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <?php include'nav.php'; ?>
    </header>
    <div id="site_content">
      <div id="email-data">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="content" style="min-height:385px; width: 100%" >

        <h1>Daily Report </h1>
        <? 
        $current_date = date("d/m/Y");

        $current_user = $_SESSION['user_login'];

        $find = mysql_query("select * from k_dailyreport where kr_user='$current_user'  AND kr_date='$current_date'"); 


        ?>
        <div class="content_item">
          <ul>

        <?php
        $numrow=mysql_num_rows($find);
        if($numrow>0){
                               $sino = 0;
            echo "<table border='0' width='100%'>";
            echo "<tr class='head'>";
             echo "<th>S.No</th>";

                  echo "<th>Project</th>";
                  echo "<th>Process</th>";
                  echo "<th>Process Date</th>";
                  echo "<th>Current Duration</th>";

                  echo "</tr>";
                  $sno=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
                $sno=$sno +1;
                  $sino++;
                                $cls = ($sino%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
                  echo "<tr class='t1'>";
                   echo "<td>$sno</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['kr_project']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['kr_process']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['kr_rtime']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row['kr_ctime']."</td>";

                  }?></td>

            <?php
                  echo "</tr>";
                  ?><form name="test" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"> 
                  <p style='padding-top: 15px;margin-right: 50px; float:right'><input class='submit' id="sendEmail" type="submit" name='sendmail' value='Send Mail' />
                  <input type="hidden" name="send_mail" value="send_mail" /> 
                  <input type="hidden" name="send_msg" value="<?php
        $numrow=mysql_num_rows($find);
        if($numrow>0){
                               $sino = 0;
            echo "<table border='0' width='100%'>";
            echo "<tr class='head'>";
             echo "<th>S.No</th>";

                  echo "<th>Project</th>";
                  echo "<th>Process</th>";
                  echo "<th>Process Date</th>";
                  echo "<th>Current Duration</th>";

                  echo "</tr>";
                  $sno=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
                $sno=$sno +1;
                  $sino++;
                                $cls = ($sino%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
                  echo "<tr class='t1'>";
                   echo "<td>$sno</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  }echo "</table>";}?>" /></p>

                  </form>
                  <?                
                  }else{ 
                  ?>

                      <center><img style="text-align:center" src="images/no_record.gif" /></center>


                     <?
                     } 

            echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </li>
    </ul>



        </div>
           </div> </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

i want to mail the entire table with data

Comment: A Google search for "PHP send email" looks promising...

Comment: @David its easy to send email using php. but what i am asking is, the entire table containing records has to be mailed

Comment: As HTML?  You can construct an HTML email, I imagine most mail sending libraries support that at this point.  Are you just building this output in a loop?  You can use a similar (or even the same) loop to build the email body.  Styling an email is a very different thing than styling a web page, of course.  Embedded resources are preferred to linked resources, and for simplicity in-line styling often makes sense in an email body.  It's still not really clear what the issue is.  Are you asking how to grab a screenshot of the rendered page and send that or something?

Comment: @David "Are you asking how to grab a screenshot of the rendered page and send that or something?"  Not exactly, but like what you said. i want to send the daily report table to mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your code, I can perhaps at least guess as to the structure of what builds this table.  Maybe something along the lines of this?:

```
writeTableHeader();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    writeTableRow($value);
}
writeTableFooter();
```

Maybe even abstracted into its own higher-level function?:

```
function writeTable($values) {
    $result = '';

    $result .= buildTableHeader();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $result .= buildTableRow($value);
    }
    $result .= buildTableFooter();

    return $result;
}
```

Any such function or abstraction can be used to construct the HTML for the email body as well...

```
// ... previously building the overall email body
$mailBody .= writeTable($values);
// ... maybe some more email body elements as well
mail($to, $subject, $mailBody);
```

Styling the email will be another story, of course.  It's best not to rely on linked resources in an HTML email, those tend not to be requested by mail clients as they're often abused by spammers and the like.  You can perhaps include the style sheet(s) as an "embedded resource" in the email, though in most cases I think inline styling is probably best for emails.  (Some mail clients might not even load an embedded resource, at least not without first prompting the user, which isn't an ideal user experience.)

Assuming you don't want to duplicate much code, the above method can be abstracted using the [Form Template Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/formTemplateMethod.html) refactoring pattern ([example here](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/form-template-method), among others).

I guess the point I'm getting at is that the email doesn't send *the web page*, but rather the web page and the email are both independent "views" of the underlying data.  Common code between them can be abstracted and shared of course, but trying to re-use a webpage itself in an email is over-complicating the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. and now updated the code i am using to print the table in webpage. now all i want is, to mail the entire table as it look in webpage

Comment: @user3239311: Well, it looks like you'll want to refactor that code a bit to make it more re-usable.  But the general pattern from my answer holds.  Move the database components further to the top in order to get the data, then with the data you go through the steps of building the header, the rows, and the footer.  Currently that's all done in-line in the page, but could just as easily be a string of HTML built by a function (or series of functions) and `echo`ed to the page.  That same string could also be used in the email body.

Comment: Can you please correct the errors and give me the sample code for me? because i tried everything i know

Comment: @user3239311: I'm afraid you've misunderstood what Stack Overflow does.  This community is not going to fix your code for you.  We're happy to answer questions you have, but "please improve this and send it back to me" doesn't go over well here.  You might consider coder-for-hire services to do your development work for you.  If, on the other hand, you've attempted something and it didn't work as expected or as desired and you'd like to know why, you're free to ask a new question about that.

Comment: well, thanks again and am sorry to ask like that. now i understood what Stack underflow does. Actually i am trying this for the past 2days. that's why i asked you like that. i ll recode and ask you if i have any doubt. thank you so much